# How to i return only results in optional match in nebula graph where result in optional match

Tags: nebula-graph, opencypher

The example statement is as follows:

```
MATCH (v)-[:has]->(:acl)<-[:ace_acl]-(:ace)-[:ace_principal|:member_of*1..2]-(v4) 
WHERE id(v4) == 'user_0001' 
OPTIONAL MATCH (v)-[:member_of]->(root:repository_group) 
return DISTINCT v ,root
```

i want to return only those childs that id(root) == "root_id"

how can I add where to this statement?

in this [documentation](https://docs.nebula-graph.com.cn/3.1.0/3.ngql-guide/7.general-query-statements/optional-match/) said:

```
MATCH (v)-[:has]->(:acl)<-[:ace_acl]-(:ace)-[:ace_principal|:member_of*1..2]-(v4) 
WHERE id(v4) == 'user_0001' 
OPTIONAL MATCH (v)-[:member_of]->(root:repository_group) 
WHERE id(root) == '0001'
return DISTINCT v ,root
```

error is:

```
SyntaxError: Where clause in optional match is not supported. near `WHERE id(root) == '0001''
```

i want to add  WHERE id(root) == '0001'

to filter results that the root ID is '0001'

is this possible or not?

I have an idea to write this query with go and pipe

is this the only solution for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so this is not optional

this convert to match query like this:

```
MATCH (v)-[:has]->(:acl)<-[:ac_acl]-(:ace)-[:ace_principal|:member_of*1..2]-(v4) 
WHERE id(v4) == "user_0001" 
MATCH (v)-[:member_of]->(root:repository_group) 
WHERE id(root) == "repo_group_0001"
return DISTINCT v ,root
```

this is worked for me

this is nebula studio screen shot and return documents there

[image: optional match witout where]

[image: match with where]